# How to use Math Expression in Cloudwatch to show the total latency across the specified timescale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In AWS Cloudwatch, I have a number widget and I want to find out the maximum latency over the timescale that is specified in the top right hand corner.

In the widget I have selected latency and maximum with a period of 5 minutes.  But the number that I'm shown is only the last 5 minute period of the timescale that I selected in the top right hand corner.  So if the timescale has 5 datapoints of 10 each, the maximum latency in my widget shows me 10 (the last datapoint).  I would like it to show me 50.  If I then extend the timescale, so I got from say 1 hour to 1 day, I would like the maximum latency in my widget to pick up that I have changed the timescale and show me the maximum latency over the whole day.

I know I need to use a math expression but I don't know what the formula I need to use is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number widget is displaying the value of the last (most recent) datapoint, and the span of that datapoint is defined by the period you set for that metric.

None of the math expressions can set the period of the metric to the selected dashboard range, you have to change it manually. If you set the range of the dashboard to 1 day, you have to edit the widget and change the period of the metric to also be 1 day if you want the widget to show maximum across the entire day.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It's a frustrating answer (ie not the one I wanted to hear), but good to know!